# Wordpress custom taxonomy logic

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm sitting here with an issue to figure out. I'll explain it shortly:
On the homepage of a webiste i am developing , i have a few tiles with brands which link to a custom taxonomy ( with some products arranged by current brand, some info , and a slider image). The slider image is the issue. Becouse this is a custom taxonomy it generates each brands page. So when it is trying to the_field('header-image') inside the loop, it returns with all images , even if i add a posts_per_page = 1 to the wp_query $args. Then it will display the first image to all brands.

```
<div class="image-container">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'brands',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
    $myPosts = new WP_query($args);
    if ($myPosts->have_posts()) : while ($myPosts->have_posts()) : $myPosts->the_post();
    ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field("header-image"); ?>" alt="">
    <?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks in advance,

Dimotro

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is.. Could you look over your explanation and see if you can make it any easier to follow?

Comment: I have a brand page. This is a custom taxonomy (called brands). You can get to the brands page by clicking one of the tiles on the homepage ([brand tiles](http://i60.tinypic.com/2e4ypm1.png) . Each brand page has a header image (added with Custom Fields plugin ) [brand image](http://i62.tinypic.com/r786rs.png). The point is, wordpress loads the image of the first brand ( on every brand page).

Comment: Long story short. I need wordpress to understand when to load which image in the header-image custom field.

Comment: okay, I see what you're saying. Could you include a bit more of the code, before and after what you've already included?

Comment: There's not much to add really. The menu is generated by WP. What more do you need?

Comment: `<?php
 get_header();
?>
<div id="slider">
 <div class="image-container">
  <?php
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'brands',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
   );
  $myPosts = new WP_query($args);
  if ($myPosts->have_posts()) : while ($myPosts->have_posts()) : $myPosts->the_post();
  ?>
  <img src="<?php the_field("header-image"); ?>" alt="">
  <?php
  endwhile; endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  ?>
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: then I'm not really sure. Try calling `the_field("header-image", $id)` with two different ids to check that works okay. I feel I might still be misunderstanding you I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get deep understanding about `post_type`, `taxonomy` and `terms` or may you can check the acf documentation about displaying that fields [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/)